# Movie about black hole getting close to Earth so they sacrifice Jupiter to save themselves

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am trying to find a movie:

- The story is about a black hole that is getting close to Earth
- To save Earth, people sacrifice Jupiter
- But on Jupiter is an unknown alien nation that couldn't communicate
- As I remember Jackie Chan was in it, but I couldn't find the movie on his IMDb page, so it might be another Asian actor, I am not sure

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Could it be *Sayonara Jupiter* (also known as *Bye bye Jupiter*), a 1984 Japanese movie?

The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sayonara_Jupiter_(film)) seems to match your description.

> It's the 22nd Century (2125 AD), and mankind's population has exponentially expanded beyond Earth's carrying capacity. Therefore, humans now live throughout the Solar System and the total population has gone well over 18 billion. As a result, there's a severe energy crisis for planets further out from the sun and plans to turn Jupiter into a second sun have been set into motion. **However, markings are found on Mars that indicates that alien life lives in Jupiter and the J.S. Project (Jupiter Solarization Project) is put on hold**.
>
> Meanwhile, rogue members of the radical environmentalist group Jupiter Church attempt to sabotage the J.S. Project. In an ironic twist of fate, the head engineer of the J.S. Project, Eiji Honda, discovers that his ex-lover Maria is one of the radicals planning on sabotaging the project. At the same time, a satellite carrying two crew members is destroyed by a black hole heading straight to the center of the Solar System. **This black hole could destroy humanity in one fell swoop once it collides into the sun. However, Jupiter is near the black hole's path. The engineers of the J.S. Project decide to change their plan and shoot Jupiter into the black hole**, thereby altering the hole's path and potentially save the galaxy's inhabitants. However, time is short...

---

Found with the Google query `movie "sacrifice jupiter" black hole`

Comment: May I add that I'm no expert on black holes, space physics and stuff, but without even considering the "how to actually do this", throwing a planet into a black hole's path sounds like a terrible idea to my peasant ears

Comment: Are there any other movies that spoil the ending quite so completely as this, just from their title?

Comment: @jez [take your pick](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SpoilerTitle) (Warning! TVTropes link!)

Comment: @Jenayah. To be fair, I am not even sure that is the biggest problem here. Sounds entertaining regardless.

Comment: Even if it worked, Jupiter is responsible for picking up a lot of rogue space rocks before they even enter the inner solar system. No Jupiter would drastically increase our impact rate with said rogue rocks, thereby drastically increasing the likelihood for a devastating impact.

Comment: "However, recent computer simulations suggest that Jupiter does not cause a net decrease in the number of comets that pass through the inner Solar System, as its gravity perturbs their orbits inward roughly as often as it accretes or ejects them" - Jupiter wikipedia page. Seems to link to original research. The text goes on to talk about controversy

Comment: @Jenayah Should work at least as well as throwing virgins into volcanoes.

Comment: This plot makes The Core sound like it was based on 100% fact.